# Can you replicate data from MS SQL Server 2005 to MySQL 5.1 one-way?

Tags: sql, mysql, odbc, replication, transactional-replication

I need to set up a one-way transactional replication from a SQL Server 2005 database to MySQL 5.1 Database.

I have installed the ODBC driver and started to work on creating the publication, but I am getting an error that I have not found a solution for.

The error is

> Failed to set publication parameter
>   @enabled_for_het_sub because it is not
>   supported in Workgroup sku.

Here is the SQL statement I am using to create the publication.

```
use [Test_Database]
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = N'Test_Database', @optname = N'publish', @value = N'true'
GO
-- Adding the transactional publication
use [Test_Database]
exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'TestMySQL',
 @description = N'Transactional publication of database ''Test_Database'' from Publisher ''SRV01\Testing''.', 
 @sync_method = N'character', @retention = 0, @allow_push = N'true', @allow_pull = N'true', @allow_anonymous = N'false',
 @enabled_for_internet = N'false', @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true', @compress_snapshot = N'false', @ftp_port = 21,
 @allow_subscription_copy = N'false', @add_to_active_directory = N'false', @repl_freq = N'continuous', @status = N'active',
 @independent_agent = N'true', @immediate_sync = N'false', @allow_sync_tran = N'false', @autogen_sync_procs = N'false',
 @allow_queued_tran = N'false', @conflict_policy = null, @ftp_address = null, @ftp_subdirectory = null, @ftp_password = null,
 @allow_dts = N'false', @replicate_ddl = 0, @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'false', @enabled_for_p2p = N'false', @pre_snapshot_script = null,
 @post_snapshot_script = null, @qreader_job_name = null, @queue_type = null, @enabled_for_het_sub = N'true'
GO


exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'TestMySQL', @frequency_type = 1, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 1,
 @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 8, @frequency_subday_interval = 1, @active_start_time_of_day = 0,
 @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0, @job_login = null, @job_password = null,
 @publisher_security_mode = 1


use [Test_Database]
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'TestMySQL', @article = N'TestTable', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'TestTable',
 @type = N'logbased', @description = null, @creation_script = null, @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, 
 @identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual', @destination_table = N'TestTable', @destination_owner = N'dbo', @vertical_partition = N'false',
 @ins_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSins_dboTestTable', @del_cmd = N'CALL sp_MSdel_dboTestTable', @upd_cmd = N'SCALL sp_MSupd_dboTestTable'
GO
```

I have checked [@enabled_for_het_sub](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188738.aspx), and made sure all of the parameters are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Publications are meant for SQL Server instances, not different database vendors.  I don't understand why you wouldn't use a Linked Server instance to write from SQL Server to MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work just [fine](https://serverfault.com/questions/209689/one-way-replication-from-mssql2005-to-mysql-5-x). However I'm not using Workgroup edt of SQL Server.

The error is about the edition of your server. Publishing to a hetergenous subscriber may not be supported for workgroup edition of SQL server.